# How can I use this OR operation

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and any to other programming languages and I am trying to make a register menu and at one of the input fields called Gender I want the user to enter either `"Male"` or `"Female"` which will then be stored in a local database but I am not able to do that. I searched online but I still couldn't figure it out.

I am following a youtube tutorial on how to I can use unity with `sql` to create a registered menu (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4W90-mh70JY)
I searched online but I still couldn't figure it out.

```
public void check_input()
{
    player_create_button.interactable = (username_field.text.Length >= 8 && password_field.text.Length >= 8 && gender_field.text == ("Male" || "Female"));
}
```

I want the outcome to be where the user can only type `"Male"` or `"Female"` otherwise you can't continue.

Comment: Please don't use `_` for naming in C#.

Comment: Someone who is new to programming in general should not care about language specific naming conventions.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I don't agree and camel-/pascal-casing is not that hard of a concept.

Comment: If you are interested in naming guidelines (since it came up), there have been two sets of .NET guidelines over the years.  This is the first one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines.  The .NET Core folks changed things up slightly; the biggest change is that they recommend that private fields in a class be named with a leading underscore (followed by a lower case letter).

Comment: @TobiasTengler it is irrelevant whether the casing is a hard concept. When someone is just entering programming, he/she faces so many different concepts of which at least 50% are more important than naming convention. Telling someone just starting to stick to some subjective coding guidelines is not doing any good, as the person should then also stick to all other more important concepts.Thus, the real message is 'you are starting but please stick to these 50 concepts'. But at least he got the number of indentation spaces right :)

Answer (score 7):

```
gender_field.text == ("Male" || "Female")
```

should be:

```
(gender_field.text == "Male" || gender_field.text == "Female")
```

Answer (score 6):

`gender_field.text == ("Male" || "Female")` is invalid C# syntax.

It should be either typed out to:

```
gender_field.text == "Male" || gender_field.text == "Female"
```

or you could use Linq's [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
new[] { "Male", "Female" }.Any(gender_field.text.Equals)
```

`Any` would be overkill for two values though. Just informing you of the possibility.